# How to turn message into a string

Tags: discord.py

Can I turn a message into a string? I've tried just using the variable message to do that but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried...

`print(message)`

and all it told me was the message id and sender, and not the raw text or content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `message.content`. Just printing out `message` will give you the attributes and such values that you'll have access to.

If you're planning on seeing the "clean" version of the content, if it has mentions of users or channels in it, you can instead use the `message.clean_content` attribute.

See the references for more info on the attributes of the `Message` object.

---

**References:**

- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
- [`Message.clean_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content)